# Remote EJB invocation by local client

Tags: ejb, wildfly

After fixing all the errors, I am finally stuck here.    When i execute the pom file, I get this error-

I am using wildfly server

```
May 09, 2015 12:33:31 AM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
May 09, 2015 12:33:31 AM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
May 09, 2015 12:33:32 AM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 4.0.0.Final
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/xnio/http/HandshakeChecker
    at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.HttpUpgradeConnectionProviderFactory.createInstance(HttpUpgradeConnectionProviderFactory.java:49)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.addConnectionProvider(EndpointImpl.java:420)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.EndpointPool.getEndpoint(EndpointPool.java:85)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.RemotingEndpointManager.getEndpoint(RemotingEndpointManager.java:49)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.setupEJBReceivers(ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.java:133)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.getCurrent(ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.java:115)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.getCurrent(ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.java:47)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.getCurrent(EJBClientContext.java:271)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.requireCurrent(EJBClientContext.java:281)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:176)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:144)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.sayHello(Unknown Source)
    at com.experian.ejb3.Client.main(Client.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.xnio.http.HandshakeChecker
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 13 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.832s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat May 09 00:33:32 CEST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/163M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project ejbclientmavendemo: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

There is nothing on Internet on this error. Please help

Comment: The `ClassNotFoundException` indicates a class is missing on our class path. I don't know what dependency you're missing, but maybe the EJB client or XNIO.

Comment: Thanks, that error is solved. But I got a new one-
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/marshalling/ByteWriter


The dependencies-

<dependency>
       <groupId>org.jboss.remoting3</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-remoting</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.marshalling</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-marshalling-river</artifactId> 
           <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>